# What does the UNPACK pragma do, in this case?

Tags: haskell, indirection

I have trouble understanding how `UNPACK` works in Haskell.
Consider, for example, the following data declarations:

```
data P a b = P !a !b
data T = T {-# UNPACK #-} !(P Int Int)
```

How will datatype `T` be unpacked? Will it be equivalent to

```
data T' = T' !Int !Int
```

or will the `Int`s be further unpacked:

```
data T'' = T'' Int# Int#
```

? What about

```
data U = U {-# UNPACK #-} !(P Int (P Int Int))
```

?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The [GHC documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/pragmas.html#unpack-pragma) describes the `UNPACK` pragma as follows:

> The `UNPACK` indicates to the compiler that it should unpack the contents of a constructor field into the constructor itself, removing a level of indirection.

---

> How will datatype `T` be unpacked?

`data T = T (P Int Int)` corresponds to

[image: non-unpacked data]

Therefore, `data T = T {-# UNPACK #-} !(P Int Int)` corresponds to

[image: pair unpacked]

In plain English, `UNPACK` has unpacked the contents of constructor `P` into the field of constructor `T`, removing one level of indirection and one constructor header (`P`).

`data T = T {-# UNPACK #-} !(P Int Int)` isn't as "compact" as `data T'' = T'' Int# Int#`:

[image: completely unpacked]

---

> What about
>
> ```
> data U = U {-# UNPACK #-} !(P Int (P Int Int))
> ```
>
> ?

Similarly, `data U = U (P Int (P Int Int))` corresponds to

[image: pair of pairs]

and `data U = U {-# UNPACK #-} !(P Int (P Int Int))` corresponds to

[image: unpacked pair of pairs]

In plain English, `UNPACK` has unpacked the contents of constructor `P` into the field of constructor `U`, removing one level of indirection and one constructor header (`P`).

## Resources

- [GHC manual (section 7.22)](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/pragmas.html#unpack-pragma)
- [Johann Tibell's ZuriHac 2015 slides](https://github.com/tibbe/talks/blob/master/zurihac-2015/slides.md)

Comment: So, there is no way to unpack `T` to `T''` i.e. remove two levels of constructors?

Comment: @Zeta Thanks for the edit. How did you produce those beautiful diagrams? TikZ? The `diagrams` library?

Comment: @Jubobs: I used `dot` aka GraphViz: `digraph {
 node[shape=record];
 con[label="U|<f0>"];
 p[label="<p0>P|<p1>|<p2>"];
 q[label="<q0>P|<q1>|<q2>"];
 i1[label="<i1>I#|Int#"];
 i2[label="<i2>I#|Int#"];
 i3[label="<i3>I#|Int#"];
 con:f0 -> p:p0
 p:p1 -> i1:i1
 p:p2 -> q:q0
 q:q1 -> i2:i2
 q:q2 -> i3:i3
}`. Not really really what I would call best practice graphviz, but it did the job.

Comment: @Zeta Thanks for that.

Comment: @AlexeyVagarenko It seems that polymorphic fields (e.g. `a` and `b` in the data declaration of `P`) cannot ([yet?](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7647)) be unpacked. I may be wrong, but I don't think you can unpack `T` so that it has the same memory footprint as `T''`.